# Change color of every UILabel in UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

Is it possible to loop through all the `UILabel`s in my `UIScrollview` and change the color?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming they’re all subviews (first-level children) of the scroll view, not of container views inside it...

```
for(UIView *subview in theScrollView.subviews)
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        [(UILabel *)subview setTextColor:[UIColor whateverColor]];
```

If the labels are inside other views inside the scroll view, you’ll have to recurse into each of the subviews and do the same thing, but that’s a pretty simple step from the above. Example:

```
- (void)recolorLabelSubviews:(UIView *)view
{
    for(UIView *subview in view.subviews)
    {
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
            [(UILabel *)subview setTextColor:[UIColor whateverColor]];
        else
            [self recolorLabelSubviews:subview];
        // this doesn't handle the case where you have a label as a subview of a label
        // if for some reason you're doing that, just move the [self recolorEtc:] call out of the "else" block
    }
}

// then, wherever you want to recolor every label in the scroll view...

[self recolorLabelSubviews:theScrollView];
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped, but I'm still facing a problem: The labels I want to change are subViews of UIViews that were added through a loop. Now if I say the loop changes the labels in this UIView, only the last UIView that was added through the loop changes it's color - any ideas?

Comment: Maybe add all the UIViews to a container object as they're created?

Comment: Just another question: I tried to do the same thing with UIViews instead of UILabels, but if I do this literally everything changes it's backgroundColor except the UIView. Can you help me out again?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
for (UILabel *lbl in [self.view subviews]) {
    if([lbl isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
    }
}
```